# Using create-react-app to create a library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm trying to create a library of React-Redux and I'm trying to use [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) to get the boilerplate code but it include in the build script things like appHtml which are irrelevant.

Is there a way to turn ejected create-react-app to library - specifically I need to **not** package all js files into one but instead just pass them through babel and produce separate files for each React Component?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have managed to build library without ejecting and using internal dependencies of create react app. I've tested it with `react-scripts@0.9.5`. At first you need to install `babel-cli`:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli
```

create `.babelrc` file with content:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-app"]
}
```

Then add script to `package.json`:

```
"compile": "NODE_ENV=production babel src --out-dir lib --copy-files",
```

And finally run:

```
npm run compile
```

This will compile all sources from `src` to `lib` directory and simply copy the remaining files. Don't forget to declare the main file in `package.json` (e.g. `"main"="lib/index.js"`).

However there is one caveat. If you are using files which cannot be compiled with babel (e.g. css or fonts) then the users of your library would need to set up appropriate (webpack) loaders.

Comment: For current `react-scripts@2.1.3` (which uses Babel 7) instead of `babel-cli` install `@babel/cli` and `@babel/preset-react`

Comment: If you're on Windows you'll need to add cross-env in order for the above compile command to work: `npm install --save-dev cross-env` , `"compile": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel src --out-dir lib --copy-files",`

Comment: would be easier to just create a project with babel directly, or does create-react-app still do a lot for you in this scenario?

Comment: I got error ``` 
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (32:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

```

Answer (score 2):

Edit the following in the `package.json`

1. `name`
2. `description`
3. `scripts`
4. `author`
5. `license`
6. `gitRepository`

and do `npm publish`. It'll publish your library in `npm`

Comment: Thanks, I've edit the question, I need to know how to produce seperate js files instead of one big file

Answer (score 2):

this is is the best I have found so far..uses create-react-app for libraries https://github.com/Rubbby/create-react-library

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could bootstrap youre projects with [js-library-boilerplate](https://github.com/hodgef/js-library-boilerplate).
I've use it several times and it's good enough to give it a try. It can be used as a base for the vanila js libs or react libs (use CRA under the hood).

To use it all you need, is to:

- clone repo
- make some changes as:

  ---
- Edit LICENSE file
- Edit package.json information (These will be used to generate the headers for your built files)
- Edit library: "MyLibrary" with your library's export name in ./config/webpack.config.js
- Edit ./bin/postinstall (If you would like to display a message on package install)

  ---

...and you a ready to go.
Also all configs are open so you can adjust it as you require.
Good luck!